# ActiveXからレジストリキーを取得できない

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

ActiveXからレジストリキー（`HKLM\Software\XXX`）を参照できないPCがあり困っています。

PCはWindows10 Pro 64bit（ブラウザは当たり前ですがIE11）、ActiveXは32bitアプリケーションで、参照したいレジストリも32bitのものです。

32bitアプリケーションから32bitレジストリの参照なので `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\XXX` ではなく `HKLM\Software\XXX` で取得しようとしています。

`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\XXX` キーが存在していることは確認しています。また、問題が発生しているPC/ユーザアカウントで `reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\XXX /reg:32` を実行して情報を取得できることを確認しています。

この問題は一部のPCでのみ発生していることから環境的なものと考えていますが。。。

このような場合、原因について考えられることはありますでしょうか？また、他に調査すべき点はあるでしょうか？

ちなみに、タイミング的にWindows10のメジャーバージョンアップ（1803→1809等）を行ってからこの問題が発生しているようです。

Comment: 回答では無いのでコメントで。1809以後の不具合をまとめている [個人ブログ記事](http://blog.livedoor.jp/nichepcgamer/archives/1072749568.html) や [MSのコミュニティ記事](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/all/%E8%A8%8E%E8%AB%96rewin10%E3%81%AE%E6%83%85/2c0d943b-f582-475b-8b71-4e6e54ce69b5) 等があります。レジストリ系では [こんな記事](https://www.softantenna.com/wp/windows/windows-10-version-1809-bug/) も。関係あるかどうかは不明ですが、参考になれば良いですね。

Comment: @kunif 情報ありがとうございます！量も多くて読むのもなかなか辛いものがありますが（笑）、見てみます！